# Experience with Craft's native rss/atom support?

Tags: rss, feed

I'm trying to use the native support for rss and atom as described in the documentation, but it misses some info.

- https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/atom-feed
- https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/rss-feed

Did anyone got this to work? I'm not even sure how to name my template or what the url is going to be.

I tried the following template names:
`template.twig.atom`
`template.atom.twig`
`template.atom`

I tried requests with atom in the header and `.atom` postfix. Both without any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you can call the template file directly and it answers by default with the right response headers.

So for example, putting templates named `feed.atom` and `feed.rss` in the root of your template folder enables you to call them via `/feed.atom` and `/feed.rss`.
No need for setting content-type by hand.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, so I have a `rss.twig` file in the root of my template directory.

```
{% header "Content-Type: application/rss+xml" %}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">

{% set rss = craft.entries.section('article').limit(10).type('article') %}

<channel>
  <title>My Site Name</title>
  <link>{{ siteUrl }}</link>
  <description>My site description</description>
  <language>en-au</language>
  <atom:link href="{{ url() }}" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />

  {% for item in rss %}
  <item>
    <title><![CDATA[{{ item.title|raw }}]]></title>
    <link>{{ item.url() }}</link>
    <description><![CDATA[
    {% for block in item.body %}

  {% if block.type == "text" %}

    {{ block.text }}

  {% elseif block.type == "footnote" %}

    {% include 'blocks/_footnote' %}

  {% elseif block.type == "pullQuote" %}

    {% include 'blocks/_pullquote' %}

  {% elseif block.type == "heading" %}

    {% include 'blocks/_heading' %}

  {% elseif block.type == "image" %}

    {% include 'blocks/_image' %}

  {% elseif block.type == "audio" %}

    {% include 'blocks/_audio' %}

  {% elseif block.type == "video" %}

    {% include 'blocks/_video' %}

  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}]]></description>
    <pubDate>{{ item.postDate.rfc2822() }}</pubDate>
    <guid>{{ item.url() }}</guid>
  </item>
  {% endfor %}
</channel>

</rss>
```

If I access, http://myurl.com/rss - I get my lovely feed.

Comment: I've just answered my own question. You can name your file .rss instead of .twig and it automatically sets the `Content-Type` part.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is not a proper answer to the question. If you're unfamiliar with how to use the feeds you may be better off taking a look at the feedMe found plugin here:

https://github.com/engram-design/FeedMe

And building out your templates using that. Could save some time and headaches. Sorry I can't give you further information on using the feeds as seen in the docs.

Comment: Thanks, but i am trying to generate a feed instead of importing one.